# Listing prices: ‘at $10’ or ‘for $10’

Tags: prepositions

~ is on sale ‘at $10’ or ‘for $10’. I hear people say something like ‘I bought it for $5’ so thought I’d be sale ‘for’ $10, but should it be ‘at’?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, *at* is used more often for things whose prices change often. It refers to purchasing the item as its price changed.

For example, "I bought Apple stock at $100".

Or, "buy butter if you can get it at $1 a pound".

In the second example, *for* would also be acceptable.

For most items you buy at a store, whose prices aren't changed very often, it's more common to use *for*, as in "I bought an Apple Watch for $700". In this case there's no sense that if you had bought it at a slightly different time you would have paid a different price.